# Taurus: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-2.7, jmeter, performance-testing, taurus

I keep getting an error which says:

```
11:50:51 ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is the code which i have written:

```
---
execution:
concurrency: 10
ramp-up: 1m
hold-for: 2m
scenario:
script: PerformanceTestPlan.jmx
concurrency: 10
ramp-up: 1m
hold-for: 2m
scenario:
script: ProcessorTestPlan.jmx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should ask Taurus-related questions at [Taurus Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus), discussion here is JMeter-oriented.

---

In regards to your question, the syntax is not very correct, it should look like:

```
---
execution:
- concurrency: 10
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 2m
  scenario:
    script: PerformanceTestPlan.jmx
- concurrency: 10
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 2m
  scenario:
    script: ProcessorTestPlan.jmx
```

Dashes and indents are **very** important, any missing or extra whitespace can run your test.

See [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) for more examples on combining several tests through Taurus.

Comment: Thanx for the help it worked out, I tried it before also but I was getting an error in it. I am writing the script in Notepad++ is it fine or should I use some other application for writing the script.

Comment: Personally I use IDEs from [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) with YAML plugin, cannot say anything regarding Notepad++ as I'm not a Windows user.

Comment: Ok got it Thanx for the help @Dmitri