# Error when using taurus to run jmeter / yml script. 'nonetype'

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, yaml, taurus

TypeError argument of type 'nonetype' is not iterable.
Getting the above error when trying to run my first test in jenkins using taurus /bzt /jmeter.  I am using the 'run performance test' build option.
I have passed argument as bzt /test/something.jmx. Script is held in git repo that I've configured in the build. I have also tried using test.yml and referencing the jmx. I get the same error with this approach.

Comment: some sample code will help others help you

Comment: Sorry keep getting errors trying to upload a picture of my yml.

Comment: Do your yml valid.you can test it online in http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: --- 
execution: 
  - 
    concurrency: 10
    iterations: 50
    scenario: with_script
reporting: 
  - 
    dump-xml: stats.xml
    module: final-stats
scenarios: 
  with_script: 
    script: my-existing.jmx

Comment: confirmed the above code is valid in yamllint.com, still get the same error.

Comment: Anymore ideas guys? I think the yml Is valid from the above checks. Is there anything server side?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159637/taurus-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get?

Comment: Yes thanks, unfortunately this did not resolve my error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're using the latest Taurus version, in order to perform the upgrade execute the following command:

   ```
   pip install bzt --upgrade
   ```
2. Try running Taurus in GUI mode like:

   ```
   bzt test/something.jmx -gui
   ```

   or

   ```
   bzt something.yml -gui
   ```

   You should see JMeter window with your Test Plan, if you can see - try running the test plan from GUI. If not - something is wrong with either Taurus or JMeter installation or your Test Plan. In this case update your question with the following:

   - `bzt.log` file
   - `effective.yml` file
   - `jmeter.err` file (if it is not empty)

Be aware that there is [Taurus support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus) where you can reach out to Taurus developers. Also check out [How to Run a Taurus Test through Jenkins Pipelines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-taurus-test-through-jenkins-pipelines) guide for comprehensive setup instructions.